# HTML CSS layout 1 large image left and 3 small images stacked right (responsive)

Tags: html, css, layout

I've done a fair bit of searching online, but I'm unable to find the solution anywhere.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve the layout below responsively?

[image]

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="simple-gallery">
    <div class="simple-gallery--preview">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/657x400"/>
    </div>
    <div class="simple-gallery--thumbs">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/657x400"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/657x400"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/657x400"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried many many different ways to achieve this responsively through CSS including using Bourbon's Neat which got me the closest, however iconically it didn't "feel" very clean.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help everyone. I think I may have posed the question a little wrong. By responsive I meant that it would allow all four images to scale proportionally (just learnt there's a difference between the words proportionate and proportional).

Heres my attempt which meets my requirements

```css
/* quick and dirty reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* center element*/

body {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* actual code */

.simple-gallery {
  width: 60%;
}
.simple-gallery img {
  width: 100%;
}
.simple-gallery ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 0;
}
.simple-gallery .simple-gallery--preview {
  width: 74%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.simple-gallery .simple-gallery--thumbs {
  width: 22.2%;
  float: left;
}
.simple-gallery .simple-gallery--thumbs ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="simple-gallery">
  <div class="simple-gallery--preview">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/657x400" />
  </div>
  <div class="simple-gallery--thumbs">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/657x400" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/657x400" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/657x400" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPZjdE

To test what I mean either change the width of the body or .simple-gallery and everything should maintain their ratios.

I'm certain it can be improved, even if it's only adapting it to use whole numbers.

Thanks again to all who replied, I'm definitely interested in seeing a better way of doing this which I know exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to do it but you can optionnaly go with this

```
.conjoined-input input[type="text"] {
    min-width:80%;
}

.conjoined-input input[type="button"] {
    float: right;
    width:19%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by "responsive" in this case. One would want the thumbnails to go underneath, others would want to just resize the preview.

In all cases you should investigate media queries. It is very flexible approach to manipulating elements depending on various conditions.

The simplest introduction ive seen is short video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fA1NW-T1QXc
I also found useful this cheat sheet: http://mac-blog.org.ua/css-3-media-queries-cheat-sheet/
Since you used bourbon, you could also read about MQ in sass: http://css-tricks.com/approaches-media-queries-sass/

The other approach to learning media queries (IMO the best) is to look at the frameworks (bootstrap and foundation for example) and copy their solutions. They are flexible and tested by community.

PS. Ouh and i forgot to mention one more approach: Just use some responsive grid framework. You can customize your own version of bootstrap, foundation, grid960 etc. To suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>

<style>
.simple-gallery{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.simple-gallery--preview{
    width: 472px;
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.simple-gallery--thumbs{
    width: 380px;
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.simple-gallery--thumbs>div{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
.simple-gallery--thumbs>div:first-child{
    margin-top: 0;
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .simple-gallery--thumbs>div:first-child{
        margin-top: 9px;
    }
    .simple-gallery--thumbs>div>img{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .simple-gallery--preview{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .simple-gallery--thumbs{
        width: 100%;
}
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>                            
<div class="simple-gallery">
                <div class="simple-gallery--preview">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/540x417"/>
                </div>
                <div class="simple-gallery--thumbs">
                    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/380x133"/></div>
                    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/380x133"/></div>
                    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/380x133"/></div>
                </div>
            </div>                                    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this...

```
<div id="space">
    <div id="large"></div> 
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u8kksgbq/1/)

I think this give you the structure what you need.

Comment: I don't see where this is responsive?